# How to make bootstrap multi-select plugin working with icheck plugin

Tags: jquery, icheck, bootstrap-multiselect

I've used this [bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)  and this [checkbox/radio plugin](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck) at my webpage. Suddenly, I noticed that when icheck put inside multiselect, no default and customized functions of multiselect working! This is my work without icheck plugin: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/phnwe5dt/1/)
And this is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/koa58o4o/) with icheck where functions of multiselect are not working. The functionality which I need working with icheck too:

```
$('#data-type').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    buttonWidth: '90%',
    nonSelectedText: 'Select multiple option',
    onChange: function(element, checked) {
        var selectedOptions = $('#data-type option:selected');

        if (selectedOptions.length == 0) {
           // Custom code
           alert('All are unchecked!');
        }
    }

});

$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'checkbox-default',
    radioClass: 'radio-default',
});
```

How can I make multiselect work again with icheck plugin too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in iCheck https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/issues/68. The bug was fixed in version 2.
Also `iCheck` was replaced with `icheck`. It's your example http://jsfiddle.net/koa58o4o/1/.

```
$('input').icheck({
    checkboxClass: 'checkbox-default',
    radioClass: 'radio-default',
});
```

With working "Select All" http://jsfiddle.net/koa58o4o/4/

Comment: Well, it seems that "Select All" is not working properly. How to make it working with icheck?

Comment: @user1896653, I have updated my answer with working "Select All" example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. By the way, you've added some additional code to make it working. That means, icheck still replace the default form functionality? Is it still bug of icheck or not?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. By design you need updating checkbox state manually for changes, which were done outside the plugin. (https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/tree/2.x-beta `$('input').icheck('update');`)